# Move bytes in memory without replacing existing bytes and without big buffer

Tags: python, freepascal

**How I can move some bytes in memory from one position to other with preserving existing data and with using buffer that match CPU register size?**

A more precise formulation:

I am writing some code (for fun) with FreePascal. And at moment I need function that will move some amount of bytes to other place. Built-in function system.Move is doing it rude - it doesn't care about preserving data in destination address when moving and overriding it. Of course, I can use buffer to save data then use Move function and restore data from buffer. But when moving a lot of data it's will require a big buffer. I want to avoid it and use buffer that match CPU register size.

Example of what I need with assumption that we always move from lower position to higher (Pos1 < Pos2).
Move 3 bytes from position 2 to position 7:

[image]

I can do that using byte sized buffer (→ mean write into, ↔ mean exchange values):

```
    7 → Buffer
    2 → 7
    Buffer ↔ 4
    Buffer ↔ 9
    Buffer ↔ 6
    Buffer ↔ 3
    Buffer ↔ 8
    Buffer ↔ 5
    Buffer ↔ 2
```

Bigger example: move 3 bytes from position 3 to position 15

[image]

Algorithm now will look like this:

```
    15 → Buffer
    3 → 15
    Buffer ↔ 12
    Buffer ↔ 9
    Buffer ↔ 6
    Buffer ↔ 3

    16 → Buffer
    4 → 16
    Buffer ↔ 13
    Buffer ↔ 10
    Buffer ↔ 7
    Buffer ↔ 4

    17 → Buffer
    5 → 17
    Buffer ↔ 14
    Buffer ↔ 11
    Buffer ↔ 8
    Buffer ↔ 5
```

In previous example there was one big step - we move all using one operation sequence, but here there is 3 big steps.

In the way I don't understand - number of such big steps seems to be equal to GCD (greatest common divisor) of (Pos2-Pos1) and Length.

I write some python-code with seems to gives correct operation sequence for given move request

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def func1(Pos1, Pos2, Length):
    Delta = Pos2 - Pos1;
    j = Pos2;
    p1 = Pos1;
    p2 = Pos2;
    Step = 0;
    SubStep = 0;
    while (Step < Delta + Length):
        Step = Step + 1;
        SubStep = SubStep + 1;
        print(" %d → Buffer"%j);
        print(" %d → %d"%(p1,j));
        while 1:
            Step = Step + 1;
            if (j + Delta < Pos2 + Length):
                j = j + Delta;
            else:
                j = j - Length;
            print(" Buffer ↔ %d"%(j));
            if (j == p1):
                p1 = p1 + 1;
                p2 = p2 + 1;
                j = p2;
                break;
    return SubStep;
```

Assuming this is correct there is one huge problem - this algorithm deal with byte operations which is slow, and since I have amd64 - I want to make it to work with 8 byte per operation.

How I am gonna do that?

Comment: This sounds like horribly premature optimization. Why do you even need to keep the original destination data? *Where* will you keep the original destination data?

Comment: I do some list class (also for fun). List stored in array of bytes. Every element in this list must be preserved when moving something.

Comment: That doesn't require you to keep the destination data. Whether you're shifting data to handle an insertion or copying everything because your buffer ran out of space, no part of that application should require a destination-data-preserving move operation.

Comment: If I want to move elements in inside a list without changing list length i will need preserve all data

Comment: "move elements in inside a list without changing"? What operation is that supposed to be? If parts of the list are moving around, what property of the list isn't changing? Is this supposed to be some sort of rotate or swap operation?

Comment: I am sorry, just pressed Enter for new line, and got comment posted. Yes, it's like rotating (i guess). For example lets take string "cat_and_dog" - simple move (with overriding) of 3 bytes from position 0 to position 8 will result in "cat_and_cat", but my function must do "_and_dogcat"

Answer (score 0):

Problem described in my own question seems can be solved in two easy ways (look to pictures in question):

1) You have orange and green block, You need swap them - place orange block in buffer (because it is smaller), move green block, and them fetch orange block from buffer.

Trade-off: easy, obvious, fast with small blocks

Problem: in case of orange and green blocks has same sizes - You will need biggest buffer, and it may take a lot of memory

2) Use way described in question. You will be able to use buffer no bigger than GCD of two block sizes (orange and green). So, better to use two buffers: one with size of CPU register (8 bytes for my amd64) and one byte-sized buffer. So 1st You move (or shift) with register sized buffer using (GCD div 8) (for 64 bit systems) steps, and then You finish with byte sized buffer.

Trade-off: do not require big buffer

Problem: If GCD of two block's sizes is less than register size - we go **VERY** slow (because only byte sized shift operation available in this case). Not obvious at all.

I have made two functions to test this two solutions

```
// License: LGPL
//──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
procedure MemoryMove(const Pos1, Pos2: Pointer; const Len: PtrUInt);
  var
    // Memory addresses
    MemPos1:     PtrUInt;  // bottom block address
    MemPos2:     PtrUInt;  // top block address
    CurPos:      PtrUInt;  // current position
    CurPos1:     PtrUInt;  // current position 1
    CurPos2:     PtrUInt;  // current position 2
    CurPosLimit: PtrUInt;
    // Memory sizes
    MemSize1:    PtrUInt;  // size of bottom memory block
    MemSize2:    PtrUInt;  // size of top memory block
    // Counters
    BufSizeReq:  PtrUInt;  // buffer size required
    // Counters for buffers
    BufCount:    PtrUInt;
    // Mini buffers
    BufReg:      PtrUInt;  // buffer match pointer (registers) size
    BufByte:     Int8U;    // byte sized buffer
    // Temporary variables
    TempReg:     PtrUInt;
    TempByte:    Int8U;
    // Variables for iterations
    Count: IntU;
  begin
    // This code is not obvious, see manual or other documentation
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539341/move-bytes-in-memory-without-replacing-existing-bytes-and-without-big-buffer

    // Check parameters
    // for being out of memory bounds
    if (PtrUInt(Pos1) > High(PtrUInt) - Len) OR (PtrUInt(Pos2) > High(PtrUInt) - Len) then
    begin
      raise Exception.Create(rsMemOutOfBounds);
    end;
    // Does it make sense to do anything?
    if (Pos1 = Pos2) OR (Len = 0) then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;

    // Move operation interpreted as cycle shifting from low to high address

    // Convert parameters of Move operation to cycle shifting
    if Pos1 < Pos2 then
    begin
      MemPos1  := PtrUInt(Pos1);
      MemPos2  := PtrUInt(Pos2);
      MemSize1 := Len;
      MemSize2 := PtrUInt(Pos2) - PtrUInt(Pos1);
    end
    else
    begin
      MemPos1  := PtrUInt(Pos2);
      MemPos2  := PtrUInt(Pos2) + Len;
      MemSize1 := PtrUInt(Pos1) - PtrUInt(Pos2);
      MemSize2 := Len;
    end;

    // Buffer can't be bigger than GCD of two block sizes
    BufSizeReq := GCD(MemSize1, MemSize2);

    // Prepare some variables
    CurPos1  := MemPos1;
    CurPos2  := MemPos2;
    BufCount := 0;

    // Shift with different buffer sizes
    // Start with biggest, end with smallest

    // Using pointer-size buffer

    // Calculate amount of mini buffers needed to fit required buffer size
    if SizeOf(Pointer) >= SizeOf(BufReg) then
    begin
      BufCount   := BufSizeReq div SizeOf(BufReg);
      BufSizeReq := BufSizeReq - BufCount * SizeOf(BufReg);
    end;
    // Shift data with current buffer size and count
    Count := 1;
    while Count <= BufCount do
    begin
      // First step
      BufReg := PtrUInt(Pointer(CurPos2)^);
      PtrUInt(Pointer(CurPos2)^) := PtrUInt(Pointer(CurPos1)^);
      // Next steps done in loop
      CurPos      := CurPos2;
      CurPosLimit := CurPos2 - MemSize2 + MemSize1;
      repeat
        // Calculate where current element from buffer should be placed
        if (CurPos < CurPosLimit) then
        begin
          CurPos := CurPos + MemSize2;
        end
        else
        begin
          CurPos := CurPos - MemSize1;
        end;
        // Exchange value from buffer with current memory position
        TempReg := BufReg;
        BufReg  := PtrUInt(Pointer(CurPos)^);
        PtrUInt(Pointer(CurPos)^) := TempReg;
      until CurPos = CurPos1; // very bad condition - one mistake and loop will be infinite
      CurPos1 := CurPos1 + SizeOf(BufReg);
      CurPos2 := CurPos2 + SizeOf(BufReg);
      Count   := Count + 1;
    end;

    // NOTE: below code is copy-paste+edit of code above
    // It's very bad for readability, but good for speed

    // Using one-byte-size buffer
    // This **IS** necessarily

    // Calculate amount of mini buffers needed to fit required buffer size
    BufCount   := BufSizeReq;
    // Shift data with current buffer size and count
    Count := 1;
    while Count <= BufCount do
    begin
      // First step
      BufByte := Int8U(Pointer(CurPos2)^);
      Int8U(Pointer(CurPos2)^) := Int8U(Pointer(CurPos1)^);
      // Next steps done in loop
      CurPos      := CurPos2;
      CurPosLimit := CurPos2 - MemSize2 + MemSize1;
      repeat
        // Calculate where current element from buffer should be placed
        if (CurPos < CurPosLimit) then
        begin
          CurPos := CurPos + MemSize2;
        end
        else
        begin
          CurPos := CurPos - MemSize1;
        end;
        // Exchange value from buffer with current memory position
        TempByte := BufByte;
        BufByte  := Int8U(Pointer(CurPos)^);
        Int8U(Pointer(CurPos)^) := TempByte;
      until CurPos = CurPos1; // very bad condition - one mistake and loop will be infinite
      CurPos1 := CurPos1 + 1;
      CurPos2 := CurPos2 + 1;
      Count   := Count + 1;
    end;
  end;
//──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
procedure MemoryMoveBuf(const Pos1, Pos2: Pointer; const Len: PtrUInt);
  var
    Buf: Int8UAD; // buffer
    MemPos11, MemPos12, MemPos21, MemPos22: PtrUInt;
    MemLen1, MemLen2: PtrUInt;
  begin
    // Check parameters
    // for being out of memory bounds
    if (PtrUInt(Pos1) > High(PtrUInt) - Len) OR (PtrUInt(Pos2) > High(PtrUInt) - Len) then
    begin
      raise Exception.Create(rsMemOutOfBounds);
    end;
    // Does it make sense to do anything?
    if (Pos1 = Pos2) OR (Len = 0) then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;
    // There are two memory blocks
    // First is given in parameters
    MemPos11 := PtrUInt(Pos1);
    MemPos12 := PtrUInt(Pos2);
    MemLen1  := Len;
    // The second one must be calculated
    if Pos2 > Pos1 then
    begin
      MemPos21 := PtrUInt(Pos1) + Len;
      MemPos22 := PtrUInt(Pos1);
      MemLen2  := PtrUInt(Pos2) - PtrUInt(Pos1);
    end
    else
    begin
      MemPos21 := PtrUInt(Pos2);
      MemPos22 := PtrUInt(Pos2) + Len;
      MemLen2  := PtrUInt(Pos1) - PtrUInt(Pos2);
    end;
    // Moving
    try
      // Use smaller buffer
      if MemLen1 <= MemLen2 then
      begin
        SetLength(Buf, MemLen1);
        system.Move(Pointer(MemPos11)^, Pointer(Buf)^, MemLen1);
        system.Move(Pointer(MemPos21)^, Pointer(MemPos22)^, MemLen2);
        system.Move(Pointer(Buf)^, Pointer(MemPos12)^, MemLen1);
      end
      else
      begin
        SetLength(Buf, MemLen2);
        system.Move(Pointer(MemPos21)^, Pointer(Buf)^, MemLen2);
        system.Move(Pointer(MemPos11)^, Pointer(MemPos12)^, MemLen1);
        system.Move(Pointer(Buf)^, Pointer(MemPos22)^, MemLen2);
      end;
    finally
      SetLength(Buf, 0);
    end;
  end;
//──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

For test I create buffer where I move bottom half to top half (swap halfs of buffer data) - this is worst case for solution 1.

I repeated every move test with same buffer size to get average result.

So I start with 512 bytes buffer, move 256 bytes from position 0, to position 256, repeat this moving 1048576 times, then make buffer 2 times bigger, and decrease repeating also 2 times, …, finish with 536870912 bytes buffer and only 1 repeat (21 big iterations at all)

This give good GCD (GCD > register size). To simulate worst case for solution 2, when (GCD = 1), I just decrease moving length by 1, so in 1st iteration it was moving 255 bytes from pos. 0 to pos. 256.

I was disappointed - my favorite self-written function for solution 2 was slow, even with (GCD > 8), and when (GCD = 1) - it was extremely slow.

[Fig. 1](http://storage6.static.itmages.ru/i/13/0923/h_1379907189_3655714_1d800de96c.png)
This graphic shows results. OX - buffer size, OY - time (less = better). Solid black circles and thick line - solutions 1. Bottom white circles and thin line is solution 2 with good GCD (GCD > 8, best case), top line - bad GCD (GCD = 1, worst case). Gray fill - something middle for solution 2.

Explanation: solution 1 use "Move" function which is written by professional programmers in assembler, beat it by performance is hard.

After few weeks I find out that compiler gives not optimal assembler code. With some extra optimizations (-O3 -Or) result become a little better
[Fig. 2](http://storage6.static.itmages.ru/i/13/0923/h_1379907189_9844656_874771dc0d.png)

Conclusion:
I have tested that two functions to give same result, but not when I done that graphics, so it may be all wrong.

Solution 1 seems very good when You one of memory blocks to move is small. But it has some bottlenecks and not very linear (thus hard to predict execution time).

Solution 2 seems good for moving big amount of memory, when You are limited to allocate more memory. It's a pretty linear and predictable by execution time. But can be extremely slow.